# I'm getting error ORA-00979 and I can not fix it

Tags: sql, database, oracle, date, join

My query is as follows:

```
SELECT 
    s.NUM_STATION, extract(year from r.DATER), cl.NB_RESERV
FROM 
    STATION s, HOTEL h, CHAMBRE c, RESERVATION r, CLIENTS cl, PAYEMENT p 
WHERE 
    s.NUM_STATION = h.NUM_STATION 
    AND h.NUM_HOTEL = c.NUM_HOTEL 
    AND c.IDCHAMBRE = r.IDCHAMBRE 
    AND r.NUMC = cl.NUMC 
    AND cl.NUMC = p.NUMC
GROUP BY 
    s.NUM_STATION;
```

I get the following error:

> ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
>   00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action: Error at Line: 48 Column: 41

Comment: You can only select values which are in the group by clause, or aggregate functions

Comment: BTW do not use the old syntax. use the modern `join` syntax

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 3):

Every non-aggregated column must appear in the `GROUP BY` clause.

But your query does not use aggregate functions so I think that you want `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Here is your query updated (also using explicit `JOIN`s instead of [old-style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)) :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    s.NUM_STATION,
    extract (year from r.DATER),
    cl.NB_RESERV
FROM 
    STATION s
    INNER JOIN HOTEL h       ON s.NUM_STATION=h.NUM_STATION 
    INNER JOIN CHAMBRE c     ON h.NUM_HOTEL=c.NUM_HOTEL
    INNER JOIN RESERVATION r ON c.IDCHAMBRE=r.IDCHAMBRE
    INNER JOIN CLIENTS cl    ON r.NUMC=cl.NUMC
    INNER JOIN PAYEMENT p    ON cl.NUMC=p.NUMC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the query to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT h.NUM_STATION, extract(year from r.DATER), cl.NB_RESERV
FROM HOTEL h JOIN
     CHAMBRE c
     h.NUM_HOTEL = c.NUM_HOTEL JOIN
     RESERVATION r
     ON c.IDCHAMBRE = r.IDCHAMBRE JOIN
     CLIENTS cl
     ON r.NUMC = cl.NUMC ;
```

That is, the tables `STATION` and `PAYEMENT` are not needed for this query, assuming that they are not used for filtering.  The `NUM_STATION` column should be be correct in `HOTEL` -- for any sensible data model.  The `PAYEMENT` table *could* be used for filtering; if that is the intention then it should be left in.

Comment: whether they are needed or not depends on the semantics the query is sopposed to have. This wont return the same results in the event no corresponding row exists in either of those tables.